# Binding data to Header Template in Listview In Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to show some details like Name, Lic.# in header which is unique and not repeating for that particular Listview . Is there anyway to show this?

Comment: Where you getting this data from? Are this properties presented in ListView's datasource or you want to use some page properties?

Comment: Its coming from sqldatasource

Answer (score 6):

You can introduce page properties for data that you want to show in layout, get they from the first row dataItem in the ItemDataBound event handler and bind layout control in ListView's DataBound event handler:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="job_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
          <LayoutTemplate>
               <table>
                    <thead>
                         <tr runat="server" id="headerRow">
                              <th>
                                   <%# FirstHeaderText %></th>
                              <th>
                                   <%# SecondHeaderText  %>
                              </th>
                         </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                         <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                    </tbody>
               </table>
          </LayoutTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
               <tr>
                    <td>
                         <%# Eval("job_id")%></td>
                    <td>
                         <%# Eval("job_desc")%></td>
               </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:ListView>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PUBSConnectionString %>"
          SelectCommand="SELECT [job_id], [job_desc] FROM [jobs]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Server code:

```
protected string FirstHeaderText
{
    get { return ViewState["FirstHeaderText"] as string; }
    set { ViewState["FirstHeaderText"] = value; }
}
protected string SecondHeaderText
{
    get { return ViewState["SecondHeaderText"] as string; }
    set { ViewState["SecondHeaderText"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.ItemDataBound += new EventHandler<ListViewItemEventArgs>(ListView1_ItemDataBound);
    ListView1.DataBound += new EventHandler(ListView1_DataBound);
}

void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((HtmlTableRow)ListView1.FindControl("headerRow")).DataBind();
}

void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstHeaderText) && e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var dataRow = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        FirstHeaderText = dataRow["job_id"].ToString();
        SecondHeaderText = dataRow["job_desc"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Another available decision is to place header part into itemTemplate but show it only for the first record:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="job_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
     <LayoutTemplate>
          <table>
               <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
          </table>
     </LayoutTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <tr runat="server" visible='<%# (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex") == 0 %>'>
               <th>
                    <%# Eval("job_id")%></th>
               <th>
                    <%# Eval("job_desc")%></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>
                    <%# Eval("job_id")%></td>
               <td>
                    <%# Eval("job_desc")%></td>
          </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```